# how to merge/join/union two .csv file with identical columns

Tags: java

I want to join or you can say union two csv file in other output .csv file,
e.g. let say I have a csv file with fields 
a,b,c,d,e
another with fields a,b,c,x,y,z
I need output as in output file - a,b,c,d,e,x,y,z

I did as under but not getting desired output,Please let me know working java code

```
int n1 = 3,n2 = 3;//stores the serial number of the column that has the duplicate data
BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("c:/test/report1.csv")));
BufferedReader br2=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("c:/test/report2.csv")));
String line1,line2;
while((line1=br1.readLine())!=null && (line2=br2.readLine())!=null){
    String line=line1+","+line2;
    String newL="";
    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(line,",");
    System.out.println("total tokens "+st.countTokens());
    int i = 3;
    for(int i=1;i<=st.countTokens();i++){
        if((i==n1)||(i==n1+n2))
            continue;
        else
            newL=newL+","+st.nextToken();
    }

    String l=newL.substring(1);
    System.out.println("merged "+l);
    //write this line to the output file
}
```

Comment: Side  note on your code: your code assumes that both files have exact same length. If not, the lines in the "bigger" file are all silently dropped. You should check if that is really what you want. Regarding the code in the loop: there is no need to have to "continue" in there. Just "reverse" the if condition; and do **not** update `newL` when i is n1 or n1+n2
And to help to solve your problem: just print the tokens with and the loop index; that should tell you immediately which input is found; and which one should be dropped.

Comment: OK,in my both file number of fields will different only few will be identical